# What setting provides me with a warning / error for the following xaml

Tags: xaml, parsing, xamarin, syntax

I lost quite a few hours finding out why my view didn't show images anymore

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="BB.App.ViewModels.LibraryBookView">
    <ContentView.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="{Binding BookTitle}"></Label>
            <Image Source="{Binding BookCoverImage}" x:Name="BookCoverImage"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentView.Content>
    8
</ContentView>
```

Because I didn't check in often enough I could not move back to an earlier version (my mistake) and didn't know where to look.

It turned out that the 8 on alsmost the last line is causing some kind of xaml interpretation error resulting in not showing an image in the running app.

I was surprised I didn't get a parse error or at least a warning for my mistake.
Would any of you know of a setting that would trigger an error for this kind of bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug. I filed a bug report about it: [github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/5095](http://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/5095)

Answer (score 0):

enable [XAML Compilation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xamlc)

You can enable it for an entire assembly

```
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
...
[assembly: XamlCompilation (XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
namespace PhotoApp
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: this setting was actually turned on (by default from the project template I guess) but didn't result in an error / warning